# Wrong render SVG with hueRotate filter by PHP Imagick

Tags: php, svg, imagick, svg-filters

PHP Imagick render wrong colors with SVG feColorMatrix filter.
For example I take a **blue** square and rotate hue by 1 deg. Browser render it right: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNwVWK -- I have get blue color.

However, PHP render square wrong in **purple** color.

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?><svg version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
         <defs>
           <filter id="myf">
              <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="1" />
           </filter>
         </defs>
         <rect filter="url(#myf)" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,230);" />
        </svg>';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

[image: Imagic wrong SVG-render]

I test this error on different configs with same results:
1. WAMP, PHP 5.4.29, Imagic 3.3.0RC2, ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86, svg delegation: RSVG 2.40.1
2. LAMP, ImageMagic(7.0, latest-master) with native svg render (no svg delegation).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem on the latest ImageMagick.

Imagick calls the ImageMagick library to do all it's processing of images. The Image Magick library does not always handle SVGs itself, it can delegate the rendering of them off to another library to process them.

From the command line, if you run `convert -list configure` you should be able to see what delegates are being used by ImageMagick, under the `DELEGATES` entry.

If you see Inkscape or RSVG you or other library that is used for SVG processing, you could try upgrading to the latest version of it. If you have no SVG delegate, then you should try the latest version of ImageMagick.

Comment: Can you tell me please your versions of ImageMagick & Imagick?

Comment: I have wrong results not only on my local machine, but on two different linux hosting environment too.

Comment: ImageMagick master and Imagick master - https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/ https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick . There won't be any effect in upgrading Imagick (it just passes image rendering through to ImageMagick). And if you're using a delegate to process SVG images, upgrading ImageMagick will have no effect. You need to find out how ImageMagick is processing SVG images first.

Comment: I have checked it yesterday and made wrong conclusions about delegation. Now with command `convert -list format` I have found out RSVG.
`SVG    SVG  rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.1)`
`SVGZ  SVG  rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.1)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same wrong result with ImageMagick-master with no svg-delegation on Debian. See updated question.